# templates of functions

Tags: c++, templates, function-templates

I'm told to create template of function , that will take 4 arguments :

- pointer
- reference
- pointer to array
- pointer to function

How to perform this task ? I was trying :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int nothing(int a)
{
    return a;
}

template<typename T> T func(int *L, int &M, char *K, int (*P)(int))
{
    cout << L << "," << M << "," << K[0] << "," << P() << endl;
    return 0;    
}

int main()
{
    int x = 3;
    int *z = &x;
    int &y = x;
    char c[3];
    int (*pf)(int) = nothing;

    cout << "some result of func" << func(z, y, c, pf) << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This gives me "no matching function , I guess for 'pf'. Also now I have no control over what to pass within pf or am I wrong ?

Comment: As sbi noted, don't just edit your question in a way that makes answers already given look wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there. However, in C++, a reference is denoted with `&` (not `$`), a pointer to an array is a pointer to its first element, and a function pointer needs additional parentheses: `T (*pf)()`.

Note that it is called a *function template* (as opposed to *class templates*).

***Edit***: (You shouldn't edit your question so that answers given so far suddenly become nonsensical.)

`pf(x)` **calls** the function stored in `pf`. `pf` already *is* a function pointer, so pass it as it is.
(Also, in your declaration `P` is a function taking an `X`, while `pf` takes an `int`. I suppose this is an editing error?)

Note that, with function pointers, there are 1..N types involved, one result type, and 0..N argument types. "Create a function template that will take a pointer to a function" can mean any of that. Or it means

```
template< typename F >
void f(F func);
```

which can be called with any function pointer.

Comment: and the size, you should pass the size as an additional argument

Comment: BTW, I don't think "function template" is meant as "templated function" but rather as a template on how to create a function. Depending on your level of study of C++, your professor might just be asking for a signature rather than a templated function.

Answer (score 1):

To help you little bit more, try to remember how the "main" function taking arguments looks like, this will help you to see how you can make a pointer to an array.

Comment: I first liked this hint, but then I remembered that this is an array _of pointers_. So I'm afraid that's not really helpful for beginners.

Comment: @sbi You are right, but it works and it is imho kind of language issue (array vs. pointer to first element).

Answer (score 1):

You now have some problems left...

`TYPE (*P)(x)` says you expect a pointer to function that takes an argument of type `x` - change it to an existing type.

In the expression `func(z, y, c, pf(x))` you try to call the function pointer `pf` instead of just passing it.

Then you are calling `func` with parameters based on different types for the first 3 parameters, `int` and `char`, but `func` expects them to be based on the same type.
Try writing down with what types `func` will be called with and try matching that to a signature for `func` with `TYPE` being substituted to say `int`.

E.g. if you have the following:

```
template<typename T> void f(T* a, T* b);
```

and try to call it like this:

```
int* a = 0;
int* b = 0;
f(a, b);
```

the compiler instantiates and calls a function

```
void f<int>(int*, int*);
```

But if you do the following:

```
int*  a = 0;
char* b = 0;
f(a, b);
```

what should be called?

```
void f<int> (int*,  int* ); // doesn't match, 2nd argument is char*
void f<char>(char*, char*); // doesn't match, 1st argument is int*
```

Comment: Now I was trying : template<typename int> int func(int *L, int &M, char *K, int (*P)(int))
{
    cout << L << "," << M << "," << K[0] << "," << P() << endl;
    return 0;    
}

but that gives me awful errors

Comment: @anotr67: No, i didn't mean to change the function but to imagine how it looks when the compiler substitutes `TYPE` with e.g. `int`. That might help understand why you get *"no matching function"*.